# объединение,дополнение, пересечение множеств из структур с++

Tags: c++, множества

Как создать компаратор для сравнения нормальный?И как потом сделать операции эти?Я вот накидал пока такое, но оно не выполняет операции + и -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct photo
{

    int god;
    /*char firm;
     char model;
     int price;
     int zoom;
     char format;
     int ves;
     int pixels;*/
} pa[9];

void vvod(int k)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {

        cout<<"god?";
        cin>>pa[i].god;
        /*  cout<<"firm?";
         cin>>pa[i].firm;
         cout<<"model";
         cin>>pa[i].model;
         cout<<"price?";
         cin>>pa[i].price;
         cout<<"zoom?";
         cin>>pa[i].zoom;
         cout<<"format?";
         cin>>pa[i].format;
         cout<<"ves?";
         cin>>pa[i].ves;
         cout<<"pixels?";
         cin>>pa[i].pixels;*/
    }

}
void clear()
{
    system("cls");
}

bool operator <(const photo& lhs, const photo& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.god < rhs.god) ||
        ((!(rhs.god < lhs.god)) &&
         (lhs.god < rhs.god));
}

int main()
{
    vvod(3);
    clear();

    set<photo> a,b,c;
    a.insert(pa[0]);
    a.insert(pa[1]);
    b.insert(pa[2]);
    b.insert(pa[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как вы хотите упорядочить. Например, если сначала по полю `god`, потом, если они равны - то по полю `firm` и так далее - то проще всего воспользоваться сравнениями через кортежи:

```
bool operator <(const photo& lhs, const photo& rhs)
{
    return
        tie(lhs.god,lhs.firm,lhs.model,
            lhs.price,lhs.zoom,
            lhs.format,lhs.ves,lhs.pixels)
        <
        tie(rhs.god,rhs.firm,rhs.model,
            rhs.price,rhs.zoom,
            rhs.format,rhs.ves,rhs.pixels);
}
```

и тогда операции над множествами выглядят, например, так:

```
set_difference(a.begin(),a.end(),
               b.begin(),b.end(),
               inserter(c,c.begin()));
```

Comment: по моему для  set_difference() нужно определить  operator==, или я не прав?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да вроде как нет :) - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set В конце концов, `a==b` эквивалентно `!(a<b)&&!(b<a)` :)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan почему-то у меня dev-с++ на библиотеку tuple ругается(

Comment: dev-с++ - не компилятор, а среда. Может, компилятор у вас слишком старый, а может, указано не использовать современные возможности... Какой у вас *компилятор*?

Comment: @Harry, да, такое сравнение имеет место, но для хэш контейнеров например не такое сравнение, а   b == a, (если не ошибаюсь ) ,  я подумал, что  тут тоже... Так вроде бы или точно ?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вот, взгляните: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set - требуется компаратор "меньше"...

Comment: @ Harry, спасибо, вы очень помогли - буду знать